# PATH variable is empty when calling .cmd from powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

If I run the following line directly in a command prompt, I see the expected output.

```
echo %PATH%
> C:\Program...
```

However, if I run the same command in a `.cmd` file from a `.ps1` file, then `PATH` is empty.

```
# program.ps1
python --version
Write-Output $env:PATH
& .\command.cmd

# command.cmd
python --version
echo %PATH%

.\program.ps1
> Python 3.5.2
> C:\Program...
> 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command
> ECHO is on.
```

Why is running the command from a powershell script wiping out my `PATH` variable?

**EDIT**

The example above was simplified to try to get the the root of the issue. The problem is that anything on the `PATH` is not found when executing from the batch file. So, for example, I'm not able to use `python`. I've updated the example to better detail what I'm seeing.

Comment: Unable to reproduce with PowerShell 5.1 on Windows 10. The entire path is echoed. Try `echo $env:PATH` from the `.ps1` file to see if the path is already empty there. (Also note that the output from the `.cmd` should include the string `echo` -- if `%PATH%` was truly empty, the command file should produce `ECHO is on.` If it does not, it's not getting invoked. Are you sure you don't need `.\command.cmd`, specifying the path to the file?)

Comment: What OS and PowerShell version are you using? It also works fine for me with PS5.1 on W10.

Comment: Second that. I also cannot reproduce it. I presume the issue would be that command.cmd is not executed at all.

Comment: It seems pointless to run a batch file from powershell which does something that powershell also does as easily. An alternative to Jeroen's example is also available: `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path")`

Comment: Try deliberately changing the path to something short and simple in the `.ps1`, to see if it's some kind of problem with length or escape characters. (I doubt it, but hey.) Also, try explicitly invoking `cmd.exe /c` from PoSH to run the `.cmd`, rather than relying on whatever mechanism does this implicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like somehow my powershell session got messed up. Powershell had an explicitly defined `$env:PATH` variable which worked correctly, but anything in the context of `command.exe` had an undefined `%PATH%` variable. I still don't understand how this would have happened, but creating a new powershell session corrected the issue.

Comment: there's no `command.exe`. There's `command.com` in DOS and `cmd.exe` in Windows

Answer (score 0):

I had exact same problem. In my case, the reason was too long `$env:PATH` variable in Powershell. When invoking `.cmd` from Powerhell, the PATH does not get truncated (as one would expect), but is just empty.

There are some [docs on commandline length limit](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031210-00/?p=41553). In my test, the max length of PATH was 8184 chars.

Opening a new Powershell session may help mitigate the problem (if only the current process `PATH` var exceeds the threshold, not the system-wide one).

Answer (score -2):

What is the purpose of your script?

If you're trying to get the current pathway that the script is in for PowerShell, try the command "Get-Location". It will return the current pathway

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Location

Path
----
C:\Windows\system32
```

If you want to put it into a variable do the following

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $Path = (Get-Location).path
PS C:\Windows\system32> $Path
C:\Windows\system32
```

Comment: Get-Location tells the current working directory which might not be where the .ps1 script is located. $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Source)

Comment: Ah I see, I misunderstood what the question was asking. Yes the $MyInvocation variable would be the most logical source here.